# How to show log passing through the specific commit in git?

Tags: git, git-log

I have a repo with a master containing almost only merge-commits. When I do `git log` it sometimes follows first parent and sometimes the second. I want to see output of the `git log` that passes through a specific commit - starting from HEAD.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Running `git log --no-merges specific..HEAD` should show you that history as well as ignoring merge commits.